# How to change the position of the buttons

Tags: python, pyside2

In my program I have a set of buttons where each button can be repositioned .. I succeeded in changing the position of one button. How to change the position of the chosen button.

For example, when you drag the button 1, only the button 1 moves
When you drag button 2, only button 2 moves

[image]

My code :

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *


class mainHMI (QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = {}
        self.width = 705
        self.height = 437
        self.Label = QLabel(self)
        self.Label.resize(self.width, self.height)
        #Add Button
        mainHMI.fun_button(self)
        #show
        self.show()

    def fun_button (self) :
        i=5
        self.nbre_Lighthing_in_floor0 = 10
        for j in range(self.nbre_Lighthing_in_floor0) :
            self.button[j] = QPushButton(self.Label)
            self.button[j].setGeometry(QRect(i, 90, 50, 50))
            self.button[j].setMinimumSize(QSize(55, 55))
            self.button[j].setMaximumSize(QSize(55, 55))
            self.button[j].setText("button"+str(j+1))
            self.button[j].setObjectName("button"+str(j))
            self.button[j].show()
            i = i + 70

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,vent):
        self.button[0].move(vent.x(),vent.y())


if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     ui = mainHMI()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: First of all, I find very weird that you contain buttons in the dict, not the list, but why in the `mouseMoveEvent` you write `self.button[0]`, shouldn't be it changing only first button always?

Comment: @Arzybek, I can move one button by changing the value of i self.button [i]. But I am in favor of changing any button and I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimplement `mouseMoveEvent` in a QPushButton subclass to move the button.

```
class MovableButton(QPushButton):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.origin = event.pos()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.windowPos().toPoint() - self.origin)
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)


class mainHMI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = {}
        self.width = 705
        self.height = 437
        self.Label = QLabel(self)
        self.Label.resize(self.width, self.height)
        #Add Button
        mainHMI.fun_button(self)
        #show
        self.show()

    def fun_button (self) :
        i=5
        self.nbre_Lighthing_in_floor0 = 10
        for j in range(self.nbre_Lighthing_in_floor0) :
            self.button[j] = MovableButton(self.Label)
            self.button[j].setGeometry(QRect(i, 90, 50, 50))
            self.button[j].setMinimumSize(QSize(55, 55))
            self.button[j].setMaximumSize(QSize(55, 55))
            self.button[j].setText("button"+str(j+1))
            self.button[j].setObjectName("button"+str(j))
            self.button[j].show()
            i = i + 70


if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     ui = mainHMI()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```